# Why does data binding on a dynamically loaded control break?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xamlreader

Currently I'm designing an application that should at one point be able to create a report from a Xaml template File using Data Binding (involving a `FlowDocument`).

The idea was to simply convert a dynamically loaded control via BlockUIContainer to be printable in a FlowDocument.

As long as I load an entire file into a single `FrameworkElement` and set the `DataContext` property, the Data Binding works like a charm.

```
foreach (Order order in orders)
{
    BlockUIContainer container = new BlockUIContainer();
    container.Child = (FrameworkElement)GetOrderControl();
    (container.Child as FrameworkElement).DataContext = order;
    document.Blocks.Add(container);
}
Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
    new Action(() => { return; }));
```

All the `GetOrderControl()` method does is read from a `FileStream` a parse the content via `XamlReader.Load()`. The file is structured like this:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Country}" />
    ...
</Gird>
```

Now the application should add `BlockUIContainer`s dynamically according to the dataset. I need to do it in code behind to implement custom pagination, because the reports might get longer than one page.

Since I only want a single template file, I've packed my header, footer and grouping controls all in a single xaml file like this:

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <BlockUIContainer Name="PageHeader">
        <Grid ... />
    </BlockUIContainer>
    <BlockUIContainer Name="Element">
        <Grid ... />
    </BlockUIContainer>
</FlowDocument>
```

The `<Grid ... />` control inside the "Element" named BlockUIContainer is just exactly the Grid control used in the example before.

Now all I do is get the child of the BlockUIContainer and create a copy of that by saving it to a string and back to a `FrameworkElement` and set the `DataContext`.

```
foreach (Order order in orders)
{
    BlockUIContainer container = new BlockUIContainer();
    container.Child = (FrameworkElement)XamlReader.Parse(XamlWriter.Save(elementControl));
    (container.Child as FrameworkElement).DataContext = order;
    document.Blocks.Add(container);
}
Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
    new Action(() => { return; }));
```

Here however the data binding is not evaluating. I tried calling the `UpdateLayout()` method on the `FrameworkElement` after setting the `DataContext`. 
That does evaluate at least some Bindings in a `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DangerousGoods}" />` for a `<Style>` Element setting the Visibility of some child controls, but none of the Bindings like `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Country}" />` are not evaluated.

I'm at a loss here. How do I get the remaining bindings to work again after parsing them? I don't really want to create several files for one document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the error... the Bindings get evaluated the first time the control is created. 
The `XamlWriter` then "destroys" the Binding by evaluating the text and writing the original text output (which was empty) into the element's `Text` property.